# Python Pandas create new columns from existing one avoiding row iteration

Tags: python, pandas

### Heading ##I have this df['title'] column:

```
Apartamento en Venta     
Proyecto Nuevo de Apartamentos
Proyecto Nuevo de Apartamentos
Lote en Venta     
Casa Campestre en Venta     
Proyecto Nuevo de Apartamentos
```

Based on this column I want to create three new ones:

```
df['property_type'] => (House, Apartment, Lot, etc)
df['property_status'] => (New, Used)
df['ofert_type'] => (Sale, Rent)
```

I'm achieving this through row iteration and splitting:

```
df['tipo_inmueble'] = ''
df['estado_inmueble'] = ''
df['tipo_oferta'] = ''

for data in range(len(df)):
    if 'Proyecto Nuevo de' in df.loc[data,'title']:
        df.loc[data,'property_type'] = df.loc[data,'title'].split('Proyecto Nuevo de')[1]
        df.loc[data,'property_type'] = str(df.loc[data,'property_type']).split(' ')[1][:-1]
        df.loc[data,'property_status'] = 'new'
        df.loc[data,'ofert_type'] = 'sale'
    else: 
        df.loc[data,'property_type'] = df.loc[data,'title'].split(' en ')[0]
        df.loc[data,'property_status'] = 'used'
        df.loc[data,'ofert_type'] = df.loc[data,'title'].split(' en ')[1].split(' ')[0].lower()
```

But it seems this approach takes too much time to process the entire data frame. I'm in search of a more "pandas" solution.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function and use the .apply function- might be faster although you are still iterating.

```
def property_split(row):
        if row['delta_points'] == 'apartment:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
df['apartment'] = df.apply (lambda row: property_split(row), axis=1)
```